# Динамический текст без .fill() Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Есть текст который обновляется в главном цикле (f'Buffer size: {len(pbuffer.buffer)}.'), и когда размер массива pbuffer.buffer обновляется, то в тексте такая каша:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я знаю что можно исправить через screen.fill((0, 0, 0)), но тогда у меня ломаются другие механики. Как можно применить screen.fill только для текста?

##### Пример кода:

```python
from pygame import (init as pg_init, quit as pg_quit,QUIT as ev_quit, K_c as key_c)
from pygame.display import (set_mode, set_caption as win_title, flip as display_flip)
 
from pygame.rect import Rect
from pygame.draw import rect
 
from pygame.font import init as font_init, SysFont
from pygame.event import get as pg_ev_get
from pygame.key import get_pressed
 
from sys import exit as sys_exit
 
pg_init()
font_init()
 
window = set_mode((800, 800))
 
win_title('titl')
 
running = True
 
font = SysFont('Arial', 16)
 
x = 30
 
while running:
    r_rect = Rect(x, 0, 50, 50)
    _rect = rect(window, (255, 255, 255), r_rect)
 
    window.blit(font.render(str(x), True, (255, 255, 255)), (0, 0))
 
    for event in pg_ev_get():
        # Handle close event.
        if event.type == ev_quit:
            pg_quit()
 
            sys_exit(0)
 
    keys = get_pressed()
 
    if keys[key_c]:
        x += 1
 
    display_flip()
```

Comment: Использовать [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) и перерисовывать только желаемый регион.

Comment: @DiMithras, допустим, но как мне перерисовать только желаемый регион?

Comment: рад бы ответить, но предлагаю рассмотреть ваш пример кода и поправить его

Comment: @DiMithras, даже минимально производимый код не вмещается - https://pastebin.com/YBHT9Njm
при нажатие C квадрат смещается, но со следами, и мне это нужно, но и текст превращается в кашу

Comment: 44 строки не вмещается в вопрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так, `blit` я смотрю уже попробовали использовать, но что-то не до конца у вас получилось. Если вот это:

[image: Скриншот работающей Pygame программы]

является желаемым поведением, то вот код с `blit` перезаписывающий конкретную область

```
…
while running:
    r_rect = Rect(x, 0, 50, 50)
    _rect = rect(window, (255, 255, 255), r_rect)

    # Рассчитываем область текста
    text_surface = font.render(f'Buffer size: {x}.', True, (255, 255, 255))
    text_width, text_height = text_surface.get_size()
    text_x, text_y = 0, 0

    # Заполняем область с текстом сплошным чёрным цветом
    window.fill((0, 0, 0), (text_x, text_y, text_width, text_height))
    window.blit(text_surface, (text_x, text_y))

    for event in pg_ev_get():
…
```